# ReactJs change time video html5

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video, html5-video

I'm developing a site where I use ReactJs, I use the html5 
`<video` attribute to be able to view a video, I have to make sure I can change the timestamp of the video.

How can I do, any advice?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SubTitle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min2.css" />
    <style>
    a {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .help-block {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #fff;
    }
    textarea {
      resize: none;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
        outline: none !important;
    }

    textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: black !important;
    }

    textarea:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
        color: black !important;
    }

    textarea::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
        color: black !important;
    }

    textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: black !important;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

SubPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../Css/Styles.module.css';

class SubPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };

  }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className={styles.video}>
        <video controls autoPlay="true">
          <source src="https://www89.uptostream.com/9kanocdc72/360/0/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srcLang="en" src="life.vtt" default />
        </video>
        </div>
       )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
handleVideoMounted = element => {
  if (element !== null) {
    element.currentTime = 30;
  }
};

render() {
  return (
    <video controls autoPlay={true} ref={this.handleVideoMounted}> 
.....
```

An HTMLMediaElement has a `currentTime` attribute which allows you to change the time of a source.  It is defined in seconds. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime

By using Ref Callback, once the Video Element has mounted, you will be passed the element which allows you to set its `currentTime`.

The `null` check is because, when the Video is unmounted e.g. the component is unmounted, this Ref Callback is also called, but this time the parameter is null.

A working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/3vyjo04xqp

Comment: I saw the example, now it seems no longer available.
What I have to do is clicking on a series of buttons, I have to make sure to change the time of the video.So I don't know how I can do using your video ref example.

Comment: I saw the link, but there is only one button which, if clicked, calls a function passed as props.
I did not understand what centers on this?

Comment: Any tips on how to save currentTime on a state?